# Best way to trigger filters for Backbone.js collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Hi all I am creating my first Backbone.js app. It is basically a collection that renders the data in a table. What I want to do is to be able to filter and sort data. 
What is the best way to do it? Should I use the Router or store some params that render will take into consideration.

I think the Router will get really complex soon as I am going to have 3-4 filters and 1 order option.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add methods on my collections for the filtering and sorting, and using a view to just render an arbitrary collection, that might be filtered or ordered.

For ordering there is a built in hook: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-comparator

For filtering, check out the underscore helper methods on collections, and extend with your own.

You could for example have a collection.doFiltering([filter1, filter2, filter3]); 
that returns a filtered array.

Comment: That's what I plan to do my question is how do I trigger it? I will have some links that will filter the collection. My question is: the functions that filter the collection should be called via the router or add a flag somewhere so that the view knows that is has to filter?

Comment: You could have a collection/model with filters that a view modifies, and the listview listens for changes on that, and rerenders? Models in a ui doesn't solely have to contain data from the database, they can also contain the current state of the ui

Comment: I should say that there are few strict conventions on how to do stuff in backbone, it's more a tool to help you with a sane default structure, and more custom, complex interaction you structure the way you want to. Probably better explained here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-tim-toady :)

Answer (score 1):

In my backbone-based project, I've subclassed Backbone.Collection to allow Controller to add arbitrary GET parameters to it.

Here is a snippet for you:

```
RailsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'url');
  },

  url: function() {
    var base = this.baseUrl || this.model.prototype.baseUrl;

    if(!this.params) {
      return base;
    } else {
      return base + '?' + $.param(this.params);
    }
  }
});
```